# Maven dynamically exclude class with same name from different dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

There are two classes `com.package.A`, one coming from

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.package</groupId>
    <artifactId>art1</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and one coming from

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.package</groupId>
    <artifactId>art2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Notice that the artifact ids are different.

For different Maven profiles, I want to exclude one version and just keep the other version. I am using the Shade Plugin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the `maven-shade-plugin`, it is possible to [exclude certain class](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) for specific dependencies. This is configured with the help of the [`filters`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#filters) property:

> Archive Filters to be used. Allows you to specify an artifact in the form of a composite identifier as used by `artifactSet` and a set of include/exclude file patterns for filtering which contents of the archive are added to the shaded jar.

In your case, to exclude the class `com.package.A` from the dependency `art2`, you can have:

```
<filters>
  <filter>
    <artifact>com.package:art2</artifact>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>com/package/A.class</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </filter>
</filters>
```

To make this dynamic, i.e. select at build-time which `com.package.A` class you want to keep, you don't need to use a profile. You can use a Maven property that will hold the artifact id of the dependency to filter. In your properties, add

```
<properties>
  <shade.exclude.artifactId>art2</shade.exclude.artifactId>
</properties>
```

The `shade.exclude.artifactId` property will hold the artifact id of the dependency to filter. By default, this configuration would select `art2`. Then, in the `<filter>` configuration of the Shade Plugin, you can use `<artifact>com.package:${shade.exclude.artifactId}</artifact>`.

Here's a full configuration of this in action:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.3</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>shade</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
          </goals>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <configuration>
            <filters>
              <filter>
                <artifact>com.package:${shade.exclude.artifactId}</artifact>
                <excludes>
                  <exclude>com/package/A.class</exclude>
                </excludes>
              </filter>
            </filters>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
<properties>
  <shade.exclude.artifactId>art2</shade.exclude.artifactId>
</properties>
```

Running `mvn clean package` will create an uber jar with the `A.class` from `art1` since the one from `art2` was excluded. And then, running `mvn clean package -Dshade.exclude.artifactId=art1` will keep this time `A.class` from the dependency `art2` since the one from `art1` was excluded.